# can I duplicate my nodes in Drupal ? (to later slightly change them)

Tags: drupal

can I duplicate my nodes in Drupal ? (to later slightly change them)

My customer needs to add several nodes with same content (except for one image) and he would prefer to not have to fill the same content multiple times for each similar node.

thanks

Comment: Can't you do that with PHPmyAdmin? AFAIK, Drupal doesn't allow content duplication without manual copy-pasting.

Comment: No, you can't do that with phpMyAdmin. I mean: in theory you can of course, but a Drupal node is spread out across multiple tables, so it's not as easy as duplicating a single row.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [Node clone](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_clone) module to do so. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows users to make a copy of an existing item of site content (a node) and then edit that copy. The authorship is set to the current user, the menu and url aliases are reset, and the words "Clone of" are inserted into the title to remind you that you are not editing the original content.